# Corda - Checking equality of AbstractParty, Party and AnonymousParty

Tags: kotlin, corda

In Corda we have the following type hierarchy for providing ledger identities:

```kotlin
abstract class AbstractParty(val owningKey: PublicKey): Destination {

    /** Anonymised parties do not include any detail apart from owning key, 
        so equality is dependent solely on the key */

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        return other === this 
            || other is AbstractParty 
            && other.owningKey == owningKey
    }

    ...
}

// Shortened for brevity
class Party(...) : AbstractParty(...) { ... }
class AnonymousParty(...) : AbstractParty(...) { ... }
```

Note the comment:

> Anonymised parties do not include any detail apart from owning key, so equality is dependent solely on the key

What I want to know is, why is equality defined at the root of the hierarchy, but nowhere else?

For example:

```kotlin
val wellKnownAlice = Party(aliceKey, aliceX500name)
val anonymousAlice = AnonymousParty(aliceKey)

wellKnownAlice == anonymousAlice
// true
```

Whilst I hold an opinionated view, I don't feel like these should be equal when they are fundamentally different things. I feel like this would have been better implemented like so:

```kotlin
abstract class AbstractParty(val owningKey: PublicKey): Destination {

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        return other === this 
            || other is AbstractParty 
            && other.javaClass == javaClass
            && equalsByKey(other)
    }

    fun equalsByKey(other: AbstractParty): Boolean {
        return other === this || other.owningKey == owningKey
    } 

    ...
}

class Party(...) : AbstractParty(...) {

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        return other === this 
            || other is Party
            && other.name == name
            && equalsByKey(other)
    }

    ...
}

class AnonymousParty(...) : AbstractParty(...) { ... }
```

Thoughts on this much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree it is a bit of an inconsistency.  I know you are a more experienced CorDapp developer than I am (because your previous questions have helped me learn Corda) but I will share my own experience.

When I first started working with Corda I thought (and coded) in terms of Party.  However the more I introduced Confidential Identities into my CorDapps the more I began to think in terms of PublicKey (AnonymousParty).

So I actually find this “inconsistency” somewhat handy.

I wonder if the developers at R3 knew that CorDapps should generally always use AnonymousParty so wanted to make comparing AnonymousParty and Party as easy as possible.  Just a guess.

Comment: I'm also a developer at R3 now ;-) but I prefer asking this sort of question using a public forum because it engages the community, rather than just receiving feedback internally.

Comment: Congrats!  That is good news for the company and the community!  Now I feel like I have a direct line to the president! : D

Answer (score 0):

Consider the case where you have `name: CordaX500Name` and `key: PublicKey`. Then define

```
val p1 = AnonymousParty(key)
val p2 = Party(name, key)
```

With your proposed implementation you would have `p1 == p2` but not `p2 == p1`, so the relation is not symmetric and hence not a valid equivalence relation.

The well-known name is supposed to be unique for any given key, so I think that the current implementation is reasonable. Otherwise we would distinguish otherwise equal identities based on whether they were resolved to a name or not.

Comment: `p1 == p2` should be false, because the base implementation in `AbstractParty` checks `other.javaClass == javaClass`.

Comment: The problem with the existing equality implementation isn't actually to do with the classes defined by R3/Corda. The problem is that `AbstractParty` is `abstract` rather than `sealed` which means you can implement your own `AbstractParty` type, leading to potential non-symmetric equivalence.

Comment: Ah, right, I missed that line. Yes, I agree on that. Open type hierarchies cannot implement equality correctly, so it should have been declared `sealed` to avoid that footgun.